# How can I accept Bitcoin payment in a smart contract? What would be the code for that?

Tags: contract-design, contract-development, bitcoin, blockchain-interoperation

I will create my personal token and I would like to be able to sell it for ETH and BTC. I know how to add the sell function for ETH, but how can I sell the tokens for BTC?

The ETH sell function I will use is the following:

```
function sell(uint256 amount) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < amount ) throw;
        balanceOf[this] += amount;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
        msg.sender.send(amount * sellPrice);
        Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);
}
```

Comment: can someone explain me in detail how this will work? i am beginner and have written test ICO contract which accept ethers and would now like to extend it for bitcoins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not as easy as with ETH, since a contract cannot own a BTC address. However you can use services like http://btcrelay.org/ which allow you to watch a btc address.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from Vitalik Buterin on reddit:
(https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4d5z1y/is_it_possible_for_bitcoin_to_live_on_the/)

> BTC -> ethereum convertibility can be done fine; the hard part is the
>   ethereum -> BTC conversion. There would need to be some kind of
>   sidechain protocol that can "understand" receipts being created on the
>   ethereum blockchain; this is nontrivial and would have to be done as a
>   softfork and accepted by BTC miners; if you don't want to do this,
>   then the two alternative routes are (1) a federated multisig peg with
>   independent and known parties, and (2) a multisig peg with security
>   deposits on ethereum to incentivize participants to sign transactions
>   correctly. (2) does rely on ETH continuing to have value and not
>   dropping too quickly though, as otherwise the collateral may suddenly
>   be insufficient to provide an adequate incentive not to steal the BTC.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a process to convert BTC to WBTC which is a 1:1 ERC20 token. https://www.wbtc.network/